# Plotly Changing the domain of xaxis in a subplot

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have two subplots I have plotted using the code below. I want to change the x axis domain / range to the same range as the first subplots. In other words, the first subplot has its x values ranging from 2004 to 2010 while the second axis has from 2010 onwards. I want the second subplot to start from 2004 as well, and then go till 2019. The first portion of the second subplot will ofcourse have no data (2004 to 2010) and then the second portion will have the same parabolic looking curve (2010 onwards). Any ideas on how to do this? . I saw in plotly there is an option to change the domain, but not sure how to achieve this for a subplot.

```
Fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1,subplot_titles = ['ndvi TS','anomaly'])
Fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'],format = '%d/%m/%Y'),
    y = df['fitted.values'],
    mode = 'lines',
    line = dict(
        color = 'steelblue',
        width = 2
    ),
    name = 'fitted line'
),
row = 1, col = 1
)

Fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = newdf['date'],
    y = newdf['cumulativeDelta'],
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'lightcoral',
        size = 3,
        symbol = 'circle',
    ),
    name = 'Anomaly'
),
row = 2, col = 1
)

Fig.update_layout(
    width = 800,
    height = 600,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `update_xaxes` for that.

```py
fig.update_xaxes(range=["2004-01-21", "2020-03-23"])
```